# Importing a CSV file in pandas into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file taken from a SQL dump that looks like the below (first few lines using head file.csv from terminal):

```
??AANAT,AANAT1576,4
AANAT,AANAT1704,1
AAP,AAP-D-12-00691,8
AAP,AAP-D-12-00834,3
```

When I use the pd.read_csv('file.csv') command I get an error "ValueError: No columns to parse from file".

Any ideas on how to import the CSV file into a table and avoid the error?

ELABORATION OF QUESTION (following Ed's comment)

I have tried header = None, skiprows=1 to avoid the ?? (which appear when using the head command from the terminal).

The file path to the extract is http://goo.gl/jyYlIK

Comment: Are those `??` really in the text file? when I import your data it imports without error, you could try `pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)`

Comment: Thanks Ed just elaborated the question - maybe a funny encoding but not sure how to handle in that case

Comment: Whether the `??` should be there or not it should still import unless those `??` are some weird control characters. Are you able to post a link to the raw csv file, at the moment if I copy and paste your data I can import it, you should be able to confirm this your end so there may be something iffy going wrong with your csv file

Comment: Added the file extract

Comment: Your csv has a \FFFE unicode [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16), try `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-16', header=None)`

Comment: BOOM! Nice :) can you write as answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the `??` characters you see are in fact non-printable characters which after looking at your raw csv file using a hex editor show that they are in fact [utf-16 little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) `\FFEE` which is the Byte-Order-Mark.

So all you need to do is to pass this as the encoding type and it reads in fine:

```
In [46]:

df = pd.read_csv('otherfile.csv', encoding='utf-16', header=None)
df
Out[46]:
       0               1   2
0  AANAT       AANAT1576   4
1  AANAT       AANAT1704   1
2    AAP  AAP-D-12-00691   8
3    AAP  AAP-D-12-00834   3
4    AAP  AAP-D-13-00215  10
5    AAP  AAP-D-13-00270   7
6    AAP  AAP-D-13-00435   5
7    AAP  AAP-D-13-00498   4
8    AAP  AAP-D-13-00530   0
9    AAP  AAP-D-13-00747   3
```

Comment: i have implemented what you have suggested but then also i am getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry I can't comment unless you provide the actual data, you can try passing different encodings `utf-8`, the key thing is to look at the first few bytes and see if it matches the known [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)